# Button not disabled on page load in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a button in my page. I want to disable this button on page load, but its not disabled.

XAML:

```
 <Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabledSaveBtn,Mode=TwoWay}" Text="Save" Command="{Binding SaveItem}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
bool _isEnabledSaveBtn = false;
        public bool IsEnabledSaveBtn
        {
            get { return _isEnabledSaveBtn; }
            set
            {
                _isEnabledSaveBtn = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

Inside ViewModel Constructor:

```
public CreateDiscountViewModel(INavigation navigation)
        {
            Navigation = navigation;
            IsEnabledSaveBtn=False;
        }
```

I'm also validating data on TextChange event and it's working fine. But I want to disable this button on page load.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Where is the problem at all? You are probably using some MVVM framework that you haven't specified and we can only guess, but if it handles PropertyChanged when you call IsEnabledSaveBtn=False; it will disable the button...

Comment: Are you setting your `BindingContext` to your **CreateDiscountViewModel**?

Answer (score 0):

You need the following changes:

In your XAML you do not need two-way binding :

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabledSaveBtn}" Text="Save" Command="{Binding SaveItem}" />
```

Your Property should look something like this:

```
    private bool _isEnabledSaveBtn;
    public bool IsEnabledSaveBtn
    {
        get { return _isEnabledSaveBtn; }
        set
        {
            _isEnabledSaveBtn = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsEnabledSaveBtn));
        }
    }
```

And in your ViewModel constructor set the value:

```
public CreateDiscountViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        Navigation = navigation;
        IsEnabledSaveBtn = false;
    }
```

Comment: Is this button in a listview or any type of datatemplate?

Comment: No this button in not in listview. on text change event its working fine.but on page load its not working

Answer (score 0):

Something seems to be wrong with your `OnPropertyChanged` event.

Try the following, it will work.

**is Button Enabled:**

```
bool _isEnabledSaveBtn = false;
    public bool IsEnabledSaveBtn
    {
        get { return _isEnabledSaveBtn; }
        set
        {
            _isEnabledSaveBtn = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsEnabledSaveBtn");
        }
    }
```

**OnPropertyChanged**

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                var handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
```

and in your contructor

```
IsEnabledSaveBtn = false;
```